# how to access the value of key which contains an array of objects in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, filter

I have to access the value of name in Cuisine key , the data in database is stored in this form   , the key Cuisine is an array of Objects which has keys cuisine and name i have to filter according to name .how to write a filter Query for this ?

`````
  "_id": "1",
  "name": "Gulab",
  "city_name": "Delhi",
  "city": 1,
  "area": 11,
  "locality": "Pitampura, New Delhi",
  "thumb": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/pictures/chains/3/6303/640252389ddc3f264dd0e9f2741e73cd.jpg",
  "cost": 450,
  "address": "Shop 1, Plot D,  Pitampura, New Delhi Complex, Chincholi, Delhi-110006, Delhi",
  "type": [
    {
      "mealtype": 1,
      "name": "breakfast"
    },
    {
      "mealtype": 3,
      "name": "dinner"
    }
  ],
  "Cuisine": [
    {
      "cuisine": 1,
      "name": "North Indain"
    },
    {
      "cuisine": 4,
      "name": "Fast Food"
    }
  ]
}````
`````

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by "*i have to filter according to name*"? Are you trying to find documents that match a specific `Cuisine.name`? or are you just trying to get all the names?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar confusion as expressed by [jQueeny in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77274986/how-to-access-the-value-of-key-which-contains-an-array-of-objects-in-mongo-db#comment136231367_77274986). Assuming that you want to find documents that have a specific `Cuisine.name`, the query is very straightforward:

```
db.collection.find({
  "Cuisine.name": "Fast Food"
})
```

See how it works in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9B6ZuHoH8tT).

The `$elemMatch` operator mentioned in the other answer is not needed here since it is [a single equality condition](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#single-query-condition). More information about querying arrays of documents can be found [here in the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-a-query-condition-on-a-field-in-an-array-of-documents) and guidance on querying embedded documents in general is [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/).

Answer (score 0):

To filter your MongoDB documents based on the value of a key within an array, you can use the $elemMatch operator.

```html
db.myCollection.find({
  "Cuisine": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "name": "Fast Food"
    }
  }
})
```

This query will return all documents where at least one subdocument in the "Cuisine" array has a "name" field with the value "Fast Food."

You can adjust the conditions within the $elemMatch operator to filter based on other criteria within the subdocuments.

Comment: I got the answer , actually my database had wrong spelling that's why I was not getting the answer , also your qurey helped.Thankyou all

Answer (score 0):

The two common options to filter object from array are as follow:

**1) Use $elemMatch as filter in the find query project part:**

```
   db.collection.find({
     "Cuisine.name": "Fast Food"
    },
    {
     "Cuisine": {
       "$elemMatch": {
        "name": "Fast Food"
     }
    }
   })
```

[Playground 1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XKfRZZNMhVF)

**2) Use aggregation query with $filter:**

```
   db.collection.aggregate([
   {
    $match: {
     "Cuisine.name": "Fast Food"
    }
   },
   {
    $project: {
    "Cuisine": {
    "$filter": {
      "input": "$Cuisine",
      "as": "c",
      "cond": {
        "$eq": [
          "$$c.name",
          "Fast Food"
         ]
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   ])
```

Explained:
In the second aggregation stage you project only Cusine array and filter from this array only objects where the name is matching the expected value "Fast Food"

P.S. Please, note the option 1 will show you only 1st match , the option 2 will show you all matchiing objects ...

[Playground 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tn-Xh8BmyL9)

Comment: This is definitely the right answer if OP's goal is to both selectively retrieve documents based on `Cuisine.name` and also filter the array to only contain such entries in the result returned to the client